# Looking for a generic player to play many file types in browser

Tags: html, flash, firefox, internet-explorer-8, web

I'm Looking for a generic player that can play `.avi`, `.flv`, `.mpg`, `.mp4` and `.wmv` video files and `.mp3`, `.m4a`, `.wma` and `.wav` audio file types in browser.

So far any player that I found only plays one or 2 types from above list.

Also for some reason video tag only shows empty screen with loading cursor on it, no matter what file type it is.

I only need to show these files in Firefox and Microsoft Internet Explorer (both latest version).

Answer (score 0):

Don't look any more - there isn't such player.

Instead you may want to use some on-demand video transcoding service, check out for instance http://www.encoding.com/.